# Can I disable speakerphone on HomePod?

Tags: iphone, ipad, homepod

I really like my HomePod, but I never want to use it as a speakerphone.

When I'm on a call on an iOS device in my house, and tap the () icon to turn on speakerphone, the presence of the HomePod makes me navigate a menu instead of just toggling the speaker phone.

Is there a setting somewhere that'll let me disable this HomePod feature?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you've got two devices to play with in terms of the settings, your HomePod and the iPhone.

The first thing to check is your call routing settings on your iPhone:

1. Go to Settings > General > Accessibility
2. Tap on the Call Audio Routing option
3. Try changing these to see if you can achieve what you want

You can also try restricting it with a password, but this may not be an ideal solution in your case and may end up being worse. However, it's worth a try to see how it'll work in terms of the speakerphone function in case having a password changes the default behaviour:

1. Launch the Home app
2. Tap on the small arrow at the top right corner
3. Tap on Home Settings
4. Tap on Home
5. Now enable the Allow Speaker Access option (under the *Speakers* heading)
6. Finally, enable the Require Password option.

Now test this to see if it's a practical solution in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Neither of these does the trick - the accessibility idea isn't HomePod specific, and the Speaker-Access setting breaks AirPlay. Thank you though!

Comment: No worries! :) This is a good idea, so in case you haven't already, I would encourage you to send [HomePod feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/homepod.html) to Apple. It may even be worth providing [iPhone feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) as well suggesting that the HomePod is listed as a separate item in the Call Audio Routing options so you can bypass it altogether.